# Infinitely adding to an array

Tags: c#, arrays

Is there a way of infinitely adding to an array? So far I know I have to initialize and declare my array

```
int myarray = new array[10];
```

What if I dont know how many items are going to go into the array and would want to give the user option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use  **[List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)**

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a generic list can help you. following is the sample code

```
    List<Student> list = new List<Student>();
    list.Add(new Student("bob"));
    list.Add(new Student("joe"));
    Student joe = list[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx), Although using `List<int>` is better to be used, But practically you dont need an infinite sized array, `Arrary.Resize` can also be used for your purpose.

```
int[] array = new int[4];
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 3;
array[3] = 4;

Array.Resize(ref array, Int16.MaxValue); //Resizing from 4 to 32767
```

Comment: As a side note: `Array.Resize` doesn't actually resizes the array, it returns a new array. References to the old array will still see the old array.

Comment: I am trying to create an "infinite" inventory array(actually they user can as much stuff as they want and when they are done, I can show them the list). So far, I have created the struct,swich statement that I will need. My problem is, I want the user to put as many items as they want. And once they are done I will print out list. I just want a direction. That would be helpful if you can help